# MS SQL Query to sum fields of duplicats

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, duplicates

Hi please assist to write a query that will take the duplicate companies and result it as one row but sum the Duration - (time) spend at the company into one Duration field for each Employee

```
Company   Duration  Employee
Company 1   2         Koos
Company 2   6         Piet
Company 3   3         Piet
Company 1   3         Koos
Company 1   1         Koos
Company 1   7         Piet
Company 3   2         Koos
            24
```

after query result

```
Company    Duration Employee
Company 1   6         Koos
Company 2   6         Piet
Company 3   3         Piet
Company 1   7         Piet
Company 3   2         Koos
            24
```

Comment: You should look into `GROUP BY` and `SUM`.  This is a very basic aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple `group by` statement, you can just sum your duration based on your other two fields: `company` and `employee`:

```
SELECT c.company
      ,sum(c.Duration)
      ,c.Employee
FROM company c
GROUP BY c.company
        ,c.Employee
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87758/1/0)